# Can't find tags in beautifulsoup when I search them through class filter through dictionary

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Below is my code.`

```
import urllib
from BeautifulSoup import *
html=urllib.urlopen('http://yellowpages.sulekha.com/coffee-shops-bars-restaurants_delhi')
soup=BeautifulSoup(html)
tags=soup.findAll("li",{ "class" : "list-item" })

print tags
```

I wish to find all the 'li' tags which have a class 'list-item'. When I execute the above code, it returns an empty list, but when I type it as

```
tags=soup.findall("li","list-item")
```

it returns the correct list with all the required 'li' tags. Can anyone please tell me why is this happening? I am using python 2.7 and beautifulsoup3.

Comment: Can't comment about python 2.7, but the code above - that you said doesnt work, works just fine on python 3.5. I just changed `urllib.urlopen()` to `html=urllib.request.urlopen()` and fixed that spurious space in your URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went and took a look at the site you were trying to scrape and searched for `list-item`. Then I saw something that looked like the below

```
<li class="list-item " itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness" itemscope="">
```

I see that the class is `"list-item "` and not `"list-item"`. When I added the extra space to your code, it returns the list with all the list-items.

Comment: I feel ashamed even to say thank you for replying to this. I was fed up after fruitlessly searching for the solution to this but never bothered to look  at this small mistake. Thank you very much.